# Warn when clicking external links

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hyperlink

I want to warn the user when clicking on external pages, but are there a solution other than popups like this:[image: Not wanted example]

Code for above not-wanted example `<a href="..." onclick="return confirm('You\'re about to leave this site. Are you sure?')">External Link</a>`?
Here is a working example from a different site:[image: Working example]

Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

Comment: So they open up a modal on the page and use a timeout to redirect. Add onclick to the links that are a different domain. Stop the click from executing, show message, set timeout, redirect.

Comment: Those pop-ups are quite annoying ... You've to capture all the clicks on the links on your page, and show your pop-up.

Comment: @ThomasSablik that is not going to help

Comment: @epascarello Why not?

Comment: Because it is too late....

Comment: Yes, far better from a UX standpoint to just put an icon (with accessibility text) next to the link.

Comment: Duplicate (among others): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556990/warning-when-clicking-external-links-and-how-to-add-it-to-a-link-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have to capture all of the clicks and check to see if they are on an anchor and a different domain.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var anchor = evt.target.closest("a")
  if (anchor && anchor.href && anchor.host !== window.location.host) {
    document.querySelector(".message").classList.add("active");
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      window.location.href = anchor.href;
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

```css
.message {
  display: none;
}

.message.active {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com">Example</a>
<a href="/">Same Domain</a>

<div class="message">
  Whatever you want to say.
</div>
```

FYI: This code is not handling the case they use tab/shift/right click to open up the link in a new window. Most organizations that had to notify the user it was an outside link just added an icon beside external links.

Comment: Thank you, but how do you show a "cancel" button and a "go now" button?